# How can have Mutt scroll inbox line by line rather than page by page?

Tags: mutt, dotfiles

Is there a setting for .muttrc that I cannot find that will enable this? I'm sure this ssort of thing goes against mutt purists but I bet it can be done.

Bonus question: How can I enlarge the space(inbox) at the top of mutt's message preview mode from 4 lines to more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the scrolling setting you want is

```
set menu_scroll
```

To set the size of that box, use

```
set pager_index_lines=6
```

where the value is one more than the number of messages lines you wish to show.